# Bootstrap + Modal + iPad + Chrome: When tapping on an input field the keyboard shows but when typing text doesnt

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, focus, modal-dialog

Bootstrap v2.3.2.

I have a Modal popup with several input fields of type text.
When I tap into any input field, the field seems to focus, the keyboard appears, but no carret is shown. Therefore when I start to type, i see no text in the input field.

The problem ONLY OCCURS on a UIWebView (for instance in Google Chrome for iPad).

I have absolutely no idea how to fix this so that when the keyboard shows and the user starts typing, the text appears in the input field as it's supposed to.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Test the modal with a fixed position not in percentages.
    modal{
       top:20px;
       left:20px;
    }